How to get the last matched element in puppeteer?
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const url = process.argv[2]
const selector = process.argv[3]
const browserURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:9222'

;(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserURL})
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(url)
    const element = await page.$(selector)
    console.log(await page.evaluate(el => el.outerHTML, element))
    await browser.disconnect()
})();

Input html file.
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div>
      <message-content>
        ABC
      </message-content>
    </div>
      <message-content>
        XYZ
      </message-content>
    </div>
  </body>
<html>

When I run the program with the selector div:has(message-content):last-child, it can not find any element. How can I find the last <div> element which contains a child <message-content>?

When asking questions, please hardcode strings rather than using process.env, unless the problem is really about some aspect of process.env. Hardcoding strings makes the code fully reproducible without any guesswork about what might have actually been provided on the command line when you ran it, and helps remove OS-specific issues from play. Thanks. Also, your HTML is invalid. There is only one opening <div> tag. Is that actually the case in your site, or... ?

As with your last question, your code should work perfectly fine, assuming your HTML is fixed to use two <div>s:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.7.1

const html = `<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div>
      <message-content>
        ABC
      </message-content>
    </div>
    <div> <!-- I added this missing <div> tag -->
      <message-content>
        XYZ
      </message-content>
    </div>
  </body>
<html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const el = await page.waitForSelector(
    "div:has(message-content):last-child"
  );
  console.log(await el.evaluate(el => el.textContent)); // XYZ
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

Please share a fully runnable, complete, self-contained, minimal example. I should be able to copy-paste the code to see the problem. If I can't, then the problem is probably somewhere other than you think, like a mistake copying the HTML from somewhere, or how you're providing your args to the program.

Indeed, the error is because the html file misses <div> that you pointed. How to catch this error in puppeteer? Showing the result as null is completely unhelpful in knowing there is some error in the input html code.

Where is the HTML coming from? If it's an external site or a user, then there's nothing you can do about it from a Puppeteer perspective. It's not an "error" per se, just invalid HTML which is not something the browser has a problem with. It'll just render it anyway, ignoring the stray end tag. You can use a library to validate the HTML if you want, but it's a mystery where your input is coming from and why you need to handle this in the first place, because that's an unusual thing to feel you need to do.

Here's a validation library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-validate. Why not just query based on the message-content element and ignore the parent? What special information is in the parent that you need to use, but didn't show in the (presumably) stripped down example?
